# gcm.registerC2dm is not responding (success,error,callback) and using gcm module 0.6

Tags: android, push-notification, titanium, google-cloud-messaging, appcelerator

i am using 0.6 gcm module in my appcelerator project for push notification, but when i am trying to gcm.registerC2dm method its not giving any response (success,error,callback). I googled a lot but didn't get any proper solution.

Here is my pushnotification.js code

```
var gcm = require('com.activate.gcm');
Ti.API.info('module gcm is => ' + gcm);
Ti.API.info('module gcm in stringify => ' + JSON.stringify(gcm));

alert("starting....");
gcm.registerC2dm
( 
    {
        success:function(e)
        {
            Ti.API.info('JS registration success event: ' + e.registrationId);
            alert('Yeah JS registration success event: ' + e.registrationId);
            alert('Sender ID:' + gcm.getSenderId());
            alert('Registration ID:' + gcm.getRegistrationId());

            var appName = Ti.App.name;
            var appVersion = Ti.App.version;

            var deviceUUID = Ti.Platform.macaddress; // Ti.Network.remoteDeviceUUID;
            var deviceName = Ti.Platform.username;
            var deviceModel = Ti.Platform.model;
            var deviceSystemVersion = Ti.Platform.version;
            var deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
            var regId = e.registrationId;

            //deviceUUID = deviceUUID.replace(/-/ig,'');
            //deviceToken = deviceToken.replace(/<>/ig, '');


            var host = hostURL;
            var urlString = host;
            /*urlString += "&appname=" + appName;
            urlString += "&appversion=" + appVersion;
            urlString += "&deviceuid=" + deviceUUID;
            urlString += "&devicetoken=" + deviceToken;
            urlString += "&devicename=" + deviceName;
            urlString += "&devicemodel=" + deviceModel;
            urlString += "&deviceversion=" + deviceSystemVersion;*/
            urlString += "regId=" + regId;

            var loader = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
            loader.setTimeout(60000);

            loader.onload = function(evt)
            {
                alert(evt);
            };

            loader.open('GET', urlString, false);
            loader.send();

            alert(urlString);
        },
        error:function(e)
        {
            Ti.API.error("Error during registration : " + e.error);
            alert("Error during registration : " + e.error);

            var message;
            if(e.error == "ACCOUNT_MISSING")
            {
                message = "No Google account found; you will need to add on in order to activate notifications";
            }

            Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog
            (
                {
                    title:'Push Notification Setup',
                    message:message,
                    buttonNames:['OK']
                }
            ).show();
        },
        callback:function(e) // called when a push notification is received
        {
            Ti.API.info('JS message event: ' + JSON.stringify(e.data));
            alert('JS message event: ' + JSON.stringify(e.data));

            //same as e.data
            //var data = Ti.App.Properties.getString("com.activate.gcm.last_data","");
            //data = JSON.parse(data);
            //Ti.App.Properties.removeProperty("com.activate.gcm.last_data");
            //Ti.App.Properties.hasProperty("com.activate.gcm.last_data");
            //Ti.Android.NotificationManager.cancelAll();

        }
    }
);
```

output is : module gcm in => [object object]
module gcm in stringify => {}
starting....

Here is tiapp.xml

```
<property name="com.activate.gcm.sender_id" type="string">XX932874XXXX</property>
<!-- put your sender_id here -->
<property name="com.activate.gcm.icon" type="int">2130837504</property>
<!-- get this from R.java, but converted to decimal, 0x7f020000 give you 2130837504 (type "0x7f020000 to decimal" in google) -->
<property name="com.activate.gcm.component" type="string">gcm.gcm/gcm.gcm.GcmActivity</property>
```

when i stringify gcm module its showing =>{} :(

I have already created project in google console and attached senderId in tiapp.xml only, i don't know where to attach API key in appcelerator

please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
<property name="com.activate.gcm.component" type="string">gcm.gcm/gcm.gcm.GcmActivity</property>
```

with

```
<property name="com.activate.gcm.component" type="string">your_app_id.gcm/your_app_id.gcm.GcmActivity</property>
```

also add this in your tiapp.xml

```
<module platform="android" version="0.6">com.activate.gcm</module>
```

Also refer the steps to implement com.activate.gcm module from [here](https://github.com/liccowee/Google-Cloud-Messaging--Titanium-)

Comment: Thanks Suraj, i have follwed step from https://github.com/liccowee/Google-Cloud-Messaging--Titanium-#how-to-use-this-module-in-a-titanium-project and also updated component property still its not responding.

also i have already added 0.6 module in tiapp.xml but still it showing gcm=>{ }

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with appcelerator, but C2DM refers to a deprecated service that was shut down recently: https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/?hl=en

New GCM API should be used instead http://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/